# Add Share buttons to the "link" box

Tags: script

> Spawned by https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/136760/178438

This script adds share buttons to the "link" box. (They don't come immediately, they are spawned by mouseover)

### Installation

- [Click here to install](https://github.com/Manishearth/Manish-Codes/raw/master/StackExchange/SpecificStuff/ShareButtons.user.js). Will only work in Chrome or Firefox (the latter requires Greasemonkey). See [this page](https://stackapps.com/tags/script/info) if you have trouble.
- [Source](https://github.com/Manishearth/Manish-Codes/blob/master/StackExchange/SpecificStuff/ShareButtons.user.js)

[image]

Comment: This has been implemented by the SE team

Comment: Looks like Kevin Montrose must have removed them yet again.  So there is yet again a need for this script...